# Social rating from grid view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, asp.net-ajax

i want to provide rating of items of a sharepoint 2010 list from a grid view hat is showing all the list items in a grid with branding . 
is there any way to add a rating column in a grid with Social Rating Control (yellow , blue & empty stars)??